# How are AJAX progress indicators for modern PHP web applications implemented?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, progress

I've seen many web apps that implement progress bars, however, my question is related to the non-uploading variety.

Many PHP web applications (phpBB, Joomla, etc.) implement a "smart" installer to not only guide you through the installation of the software, but also keep you informed of what it's currently doing. For instance, if the installer was creating SQL tables or writing configuration files, it would report this without asking you to click. (Basically, sit-back-and-relax installation.)

Another good example is with Joomla's Akeeba Backup (formerly Joomla Pack). When you perform a backup of your Joomla installation, it makes a full archive of the installation directory. This, however, takes a long time, and hence requires updates on the progress. However, the server itself has a limit on PHP script execution time, and so it seems that either

1. The backup script is able to bypass it.
2. Some temp data is stored so that the archive is appended to (if archive appending is possible).
3. Client scripts call the server's PHP every so often to perform actions.

My general guess (not specific to Akeeba) is with #3, that is:

```
Web page JS -> POST foo/installer.php?doaction=1 SESSID=foo2
Server -> ERRCODE SUCCESS
Web page JS -> POST foo/installer.php?doaction=2 SESSID=foo2
Server -> ERRCODE SUCCESS
Web page JS -> POST foo/installer.php?doaction=3 SESSID=foo2
Server -> ERRCODE SUCCESS
Web page JS -> POST foo/installer.php?doaction=4 SESSID=foo2
Server -> ERRCODE FAIL Reason: Configuration.php not writable!
Web page JS -> Show error to user
```

I'm 99% sure this isn't the case, since that would create a very nasty dependency on the user to have Javascript enabled.

I guess my question boils down to the following:

- How are long running PHP scripts (on web servers, of course) handled and are able to "stay alive" past the PHP maximum execution time? If they don't "cheat", how are they able to split the task up at hand? (I notice that Akeeba Backup does acknowledge the PHP maximum execution time limit, but I don't want to dig too deep to find such code.)
- How is the progress displayed via AJAX+PHP? I've read that people use a file to indicate progress, but to me that seems "dirty" and puts a bit of strain on I/O, especially for live servers with 10,000+ visitors running the aforementioned script.

The environment for this script is where safe_mode is enabled, and the limit is generally 30 seconds. (Basically, a restrictive, free $0 host.) This script is aimed at all audiences (will be made public), so I have no power over what host it will be on. (And this assumes that I'm not going to blame the end user for having a bad host.)

I don't necessarily need code examples (although they are very much appreciated!), I just need to know the logic flow for implementing this.

Comment: A note: These installers will require that javascript is enabled in order to do any of the fancy effects you describe - there's nothing "nasty" about depending on javascript *if the task your app is performing depends on javascript*. One would use progressive enhancement (adding functionality only if javascript is available) to add features that are absolutely optional. In the example you give, the AJAX calls to poll, updating the page, showing and hiding progress bars... all of that requires javascript, and that's fine.

Comment: @Chris Yes, if and only if it depends on Javascript. Obviously, pretty progress bars (and any progress display in general) require AJAX. However, what if the user doesn't have Javascript at all? My application doesn't have a dependency on Javascript - just simple HTML and CSS3. Hence, the other question I asked about long running PHP scripts. :) (I think it's possible to do updates sans Javascript with <meta refresh, but not terribly sure.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this sort of thing is stored in the $_SESSION variable.  As far as execution timeout goes, what I typically do is have a JavaScript timeout that sets the innerHTML of an update status div to a PHP script every x number of seconds.  When this script executes, it doesn't "wait" or anything like that.  It merely grabs the current status from the session (which is updated via the script(s) that is/are actually performing the installation) then outputs that in whatever fancy method I see fit (status bar, etc).

I wouldn't recommend any direct I/O for status updates.  You're correct in that it is messy and inefficient.  I'd say $_SESSION is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: Gotta love it when someone marks down the only answer without providing an alternative answer or even leaving a comment lol....

Comment: (Grabs his axe and listens for the troll call)

Comment: I have no idea why it was voted down, but....

The $_SESSION variable doesn't sound like a bad idea! I think it might work, BUT only with Javascript involved. I also still am stuck with the PHP execution length, and how it bypasses it. Nevertheless, +1 for some insight to the issue. :)